# How to write an efficient JPQL query that returns list of linked records in a table?

Tags: java, jpa, data-structures, linked-list

This is my Backend JPA(ORM) Structure:

**MessageObject.java**

```
messageId
messageName
relatedMessageId // maps to NEXT message in chain
```

Assume there is something in the message name that suggests it's the first message I should expect in the chain (i.e. the messageName is "Create Message").

How would I write a JPQL query that would return the messages in order based on the one whose name is "Create Message" and return the next one based on the referencedId value in the initial result? Is there a more efficient way to do this with streams or is there a flaw in my data model structure?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so much a JPQL issue as a database design issue. It will vary from database to database but generally relational databases don't have an easy way select based on recursive parents.

There is a few ways you can solve this problem:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| messageId | messageName | relatedMessageId | rootId | sequence |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1         | create      | null             | 1      | 1        |
| 2         | process     | 1                | 1      | 2        |
| 3         | ship        | 2                | 1      | 3        |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

With a table like this you can easily get all the create messages "where relatedMessageId IS null". and if you need all the messages in the chain in order when you just use the rootId and the sequence to select them all.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| messageId | messageName | relatedMessageId | path            |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1         | create      | null             | 000>001         |
| 2         | process     | 1                | 000>001>002     |
| 3         | ship        | 2                | 000>001>003     |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

This approach is a little quirky and harder to maintain but has some benefits in speed. The idea is to keep a path of the ids in each record in a varchar field. With this you can select "where path LIKE '000>%' ORDER BY path" and it will select all records in order in a tree like list. To get a single sequence you just change the like query to "where path LIKE '000>001>%' ORDER BY path". Again, this approach is quirky and hard to maintain the path correctly but it can pay off in speed later since you can select all children with a single query rather than multiple.

Answer (score 1):

Right... There are various options for that. I will state one here.

I understand you have a "message" table that has an messageId and a relatedMessageId columns. Your table would have a self relationship to itself being relatedMessageId a foreing key to the messageId.

Your entity would look something like this...

```
@Entity
public class Transaction implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer messageId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "relatedMessage")
    private List<Message> relatedMessages = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "relatedMessageId")
    private Message parentMessage;

    // constructors, aux methods, getter and setters
```

Now, your JQL would look like...

```
select m from Message m where m.parentMessage IS NULL
```

That will bring all the top messages. From that you can go...

```
List<Message> parentMessages = messageRepoInstance.findParentMessages();

for(Message message : parentMessages) {
    List<Message> relatedMessages = message.getRelatedMessages();
}
```

Sorry, that is all from top of my head but I belive I managed to pass the idea. :)